# MongoDB - Query Available Date Range with a Date Range for Hotel

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, isodate

I have an array of objects containing dates of when a hotel is available to book within Mongo. It looks something like this, using ISO Date formats as said [here](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/).

Here's what document looks like, trying to keep it short for the example.

```
available: [
    {
        "start":"2014-04-07T00:00:00.000000",
        "end":"2014-04-08T00:00:00.000000"
    },
    {
        "start":"2014-04-12T00:00:00.000000",
        "end":"2014-04-15T00:00:00.000000"
    },  
    {
        "start":"2014-04-17T00:00:00.000000",
        "end":"2014-04-22T00:00:00.000000"
    },
]
```

Now, I need query two dates, check in date and check out date. If the dates are available, Mongo should return the document, otherwise it won't. Here are a few test cases:

*2014-04-06* **TO** *2014-04-08* should **NOT** return.

*2014-04-13* **TO** *2014-04-16* should **NOT** return.

*2014-04-17* **TO** *2014-04-21* **should** return.

How would I go about forming this in to a Mongo query? Using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) looked like it would be a good start, but I don't know where to take it after that so all three examples I posted above work with the same query. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I actually hope your documents have **real** [ISODates](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#date) rather than what appears to be strings. When they do then the following query form matches as expected:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "available": {
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "start": { "$gte": new Date("2014-04-17") },
            "end":   { "$gte": new Date("2014-04-21") } 
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "available": {
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "start": { "$lte": new Date("2014-04-17") },
            "end":   { "$gte": new Date("2014-04-21") } 
        }
    }
})
```

How about this command?